# How to differenciate middle click from simultaneous left and right click with javascript MouseEvents?

Tags: javascript, html, events, mousedown

Example:

```
document.querySelector("body").addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => console.log(e.button, e.buttons));
```

If you put that in the browser's console...
middle clicks logs 1,4 and left and right buttons at the same time logs 1,4 too.

Is the browser debouncing the clicks and reporting them with certain delay? How can I differenciate both things?

Comment: I don't think mouse events were thought through very well. The concept of "left" and "right" buttons are inappropriate and should have been something like "primary", "secondary", etc. I started on CAD computers with what we called a cursor (similar to a mouse but used for high accuracy digitising) with 9 buttons on it. I think the best you can do is the [*button*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/button) property, which returns a value from 0 to 4 (but check for support, it's not consistent).

Answer (score 0):

```
var buttonsMap = {
  1 : "primary",
  2 : "contextmenu",
  3 : "primary + contextmenu",
  4 : "middle",
  5 : "primary + middle",
  6 : "contextmenu + middle"
}


document.body.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {

  console.log( buttonsMap[e.buttons] );   // Here you go

  // What you could do:
  if( /3|5|6/.test(e.buttons) ) {
    console.log("DOUBLE!!!");
  } else {
    console.log("single");
  }

});
```

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/huvaliq/3/edit?html,js,console,output)***

https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#dom-mouseevent-buttons

Comment: Code-only answers aren't that helpful. You should include links to relevant resources such as [*W3C UI Events spec*](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#widl-MouseEvent-buttons) and [*MDN MouseEvent.buttons*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/buttons). Where is 0?